# How to join based on the top 1 id of another table using Linq to SQL?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq-to-sql

Right now, I receive the following error:

```
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.
```

This is my query:

```
var issues = from issue in this.IssueDatas
             join original in this.NoteDatas on issue.NoteDatas
                                                     .OrderBy(n => n.CreatedDate)
                                                     .Select(n => n.NoteId)
                                                     .First() equals original.NoteId
             join current in this.NoteDatas on issue.NoteDatas
                                                    .OrderByDescending(n => n.CreatedDate)
                                                    .Select(n => n.NoteId)
                                                    .First() equals current.NoteId
             select { whatever, i, want, to, select }
```

The SQL portion to grab those TOP 1 ids comes out like this:

```
SELECT whatever, i, want, to
FROM [dbo].[issue_Details] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[issue_notes] AS [t1] ON ((
    SELECT TOP (1) [t3].[id]
    FROM (
        SELECT [t2].[id], [t2].[issue_id]
        FROM [dbo].[issue_notes] AS [t2]
        ORDER BY [t2].[CreatedDate]
        ) AS [t3]
    WHERE [t3].[issue_id] = [t0].[IssueDetailsId]
    )) = [t1].[id]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[issue_notes] AS [t4] ON ((
    SELECT TOP (1) [t6].[id]
    FROM (
        SELECT [t5].[id], [t5].[issue_id]
        FROM [dbo].[issue_notes] AS [t5]
        ORDER BY [t5].[CreatedDate] DESC
        ) AS [t6]
    WHERE [t6].[issue_id] = [t0].[IssueDetailsId]
    )) = [t4].[id]
```

...but it should look more like this:

```
FROM [dbo].[issue_Details] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[issue_notes] AS [t1] ON (
    SELECT TOP (1) [t2].[id]
    FROM [dbo].[issue_notes] AS [t2]
    ORDER BY [t2].[CreatedDate]
    WHERE [t2].[issue_id] = [t0].[IssueDetailsId]
    ) = [t1].[id]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[issue_notes] AS [t4] ON (
    SELECT TOP (1) [t5].[id]
    FROM [dbo].[issue_notes] AS [t5]
    ORDER BY [t5].[CreatedDate] DESC
    WHERE [t5].[issue_id] = [t0].[IssueDetailsId]
    ) = [t4].[id]
```

I've tried using `this.NoteDatas` instead of `issue.NoteDatas` and manually applying the id filter, I've tried selecting the first note and then taking the id (reversing what I've typed above), I've tried using `Take(int)` instead of `First()`... I just don't know what to do. The LINQ reads more straightforward than the SQL it generates.

Comment: I guess, LINQ generated query returns 0 or 1 row?

Comment: The use case of this query is returning a list of issues with information about their earliest note and their latest note.

Comment: Produced SQL and your one are the same, the only diference is produced gets one more column (probably for further use) and you misplaced WHERE (should be before ORDER BY). What's the other difference?

Comment: Ok, will make LINQ for your issue now.

Comment: Yeah, I did misplace WHERE; my second example was just to show that there only needs to be one SELECT happening in the ON where the Linq to SQL produces two.

Answer (score 0):

By this:

```
 join original in this.NoteDatas on issue.NoteDatas
                                         .OrderBy(n => n.CreatedDate)
                                         .Select(n => n.NoteId)
                                         .First() equals original.NoteId
```

you are saying "order by CreatedDate, take first row from the results and check if it equals to NoteId". This is correctly gets rendered to this:

```
INNER JOIN [dbo].[issue_notes] AS [t1] ON ((
    SELECT TOP (1) [t3].[id]
    FROM (
        SELECT [t2].[id], [t2].[issue_id]
        FROM [dbo].[issue_notes] AS [t2]
        ORDER BY [t2].[CreatedDate]
        ) AS [t3]
    WHERE [t3].[issue_id] = [t0].[IssueDetailsId]
    )) = [t1].[id]
```

so `t2.id` is always same for any outer `[t1].[id]` but depends on only `[t0].[IssueDetailsId]`

Sample:

```
    var issues = new Tuple<int, string>[]
        {
            new Tuple<int, string>(1, "aaa"),
            new Tuple<int, string>(2, "bbb")
        };
    var notes = new Tuple<int, DateTime, string>[]
        {
            new Tuple<int, DateTime, string>(1, DateTime.Parse("01/01/2001"), "earliest for 1"),
            new Tuple<int, DateTime, string>(1, DateTime.Parse("02/01/2001"), "middle for 1"),
            new Tuple<int, DateTime, string>(1, DateTime.Parse("03/01/2001"), "latest for 1"),
            new Tuple<int, DateTime, string>(2, DateTime.Parse("10/01/2001"), "earliest for 2"),
            new Tuple<int, DateTime, string>(2, DateTime.Parse("11/01/2001"), "middle for 2"),
            new Tuple<int, DateTime, string>(2, DateTime.Parse("12/01/2001"), "once more middle for 2"),
            new Tuple<int, DateTime, string>(2, DateTime.Parse("13/01/2001"), "latest for 2")
        };

        var result =
            ctx.Set<Parent>().Select(i => new
                {
                    i.Id,
                    e = ctx.Set<Child>().Where(c => c.ParentId == i.Id).OrderBy(c => c.Name).FirstOrDefault(),
                    l = ctx.Set<Child>().Where(c => c.ParentId == i.Id).OrderByDescending(c => c.Name).FirstOrDefault()
                });
```

Comment: Using `issue.NoteDatas` produces the same output as `this.NoteDatas.Where(n => n.IssueId == issue.IssueId)`. Either way, I'm saying 'get notes for this issue id, order by created date, and take the first note id' but the LINQ to SQL output is doing it a little differently. Even if I try `issue.NoteDatas.OrderBy(n => n.CreatedDate).First().NoteId equals original.NoteId` instead, I see the same output.

Comment: That produces a query that parses, but I'm afraid it's a very inefficient and unusable query, because it evaluates the `SELECT TOP 1 id FROM notes ORDER BY...` for every column I want to select.

Comment: @tuespetre please share SQL

Comment: @tuespetre both subselects anyway will be done for each issue, this is the only way to find dates (your TOP 1 with order by does the same). Need to check execution plan for indexes usage.

Comment: @tuespetre updated result a bit. It renders to very nice SQL like SELECT fields and two OUTER APPLY's - that's really good. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up changing the LINQ to have it work:

```
var issues = from issue in this.IssueDatas
             join original in this.NoteDatas on issue.NoteDatas
                                                     .Min(n => n.CreatedDate) equals original.CreatedDate
             join current in this.NoteDatas on issue.NoteDatas
                                                    .Max(n => n.CreatedDate) equals current.CreatedDate
             select { whatever, i, want, to, select }
```

Comment: Update: Linq-to-database has gone the way of the dodo for me, I got tired of the needless complexity and abstraction leakage.